# Looking for a more general term for "humanize" or "make (an enemy) seem human"

Tags: single-word-requests

When I want to describe two human characters who start out as enemies, but overcome their differences after e.g. talking or working together, I might describe this as, for example:

> When I saw him struggle and suffer, it made me realize he was human, too. It humanized him.

However, what if the two characters are not only not human, but of different species? How could I describe this effect?

Example sentence for a verb:

> Talking to him had ________ him to/for me.

Example sentence for an adjective:

> Talking to him made him seem (more) _______.

Comment: I don't think there's a word for it, since this doesn't happen in the real world. If you're writing science fiction, you can make up a term.

Comment: E.g. if this were in the Star Trek universe, you could say "vulcanize".

Comment: How many species of humans are there? Are we supposed to imagine there are at least two, *homo X* and *homo Y*? Something like *Talking to him had neanderthalized him to me*?

Comment: @RichardKayser Three species, actually. Humans exist as a third species. But yes, something like that. :)

Comment: Are you looking for a made-up word or a real word? For example, would "words" like *communitized* or *kindredized* be fair game? I'm not proposing these as answers, just trying to understand your ask.

Comment: @RichardKayser I was hoping there might be some kind of synonym without the restriction of only applying to humans. But if there isn't (as appears to be the case), a made-up word that conveys the same idea would also work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As you know, there's not a word for every conceivable situation, but I wouldn't give up yet.

Comment: Normalize, in psychology.